# Get related entity Ids without 2 foreach functions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have 2 entities and I need to find a way to avoid the use of two foreach functions:

```
public class IzigoKeyword
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Keyword> Keywords { get; set; }
}

public class Keyword
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And the function until now:

```
public IList<int> GetKeywordIdsFromIzigoKeywordIds(IList<int> izigoKeywordIds)
{
    IList<int> keywordIds = new List<int>();

    foreach (var izigoKeywordId in izigoKeywordIds)
    {
        var keywords = _izigoKeywordRepository.Query.Where(ik => ik.Id == izigoKeywordId).Select(ik => ik.Keywords);

        foreach (var keyword in keywords)
        {
            keywordIds.Add(keyword.Select(k => k.Id).FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
    return keywordIds;
}
```

How can I do this without 2 foreach functions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
return ids.SelectMany(id => 
    query.Where(ik => ik.Id == id)
         .SelectMany(ik => ik.Keywords)    
         .Select(k => k.Id)
);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks! I just had to made some adjustments to make it work: return izigoKeywordIds.SelectMany(id => _izigoKeywordRepository.Query.Where(ik => ik.Id == id).SelectMany(ik => ik.Keywords).Select(k => k.Id)).ToList(); Thanks again for your help ;)